# A chapter title in two parts

Tags: formatting, chapters

I'm writing a document with two scripts: Devanagari and Roman/Latin/English. The idea is that each Sanskrit verse should have its transliteration into Roman script underneath. The language of the entire document, however, from start to finish shall be exclusively Sanskrit.

I would like to apply this format to chapter headings also. Rather than the English heading 'Chapter 1' (or any literal Sanskrit equivalent that might be easily achieved with `polyglossia`), I would like the chapter headings to be in the Sanskrit style, e.g. अथ प्रथमोऽध्यायः (literally 'thus (or "so begins") the first (प्रथमो) chapter (ऽध्यायः)'), but with their Roman-script equivalent underneath: *Atha Prathamo 'dhyāyaḥ*.

Now the easiest way by far of hacking this together is just to put all the formatting within `\chapter*{}`, thus:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage[margin=1.8cm]{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\SA}[Script=Devanagari]{Sanskrit 2003}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{\normalfont {\SA अथ प्रथमोऽध्यायः} \\[12pt]
  \textit{Atha Prathamo 'dhy\={a}ya\d{h}}}
    
\end{document}
```

This has exactly the required appearance (I'd prefer not to have bold italics used for the transliteration, but it's no deal breaker. Attempting to make the Devanagari font bold is likely to generate warnings telling me that a bold face does not exist, but those warnings can be lived with) but it's a bit dirty.

What I would like is to have a custom version of `\chapter(*)` with two arguments, one for the Devanagari, one for the Roman, i.e.:

```
\chapter*{{\SA अथ प्रथमोऽध्यायः}}{Atha Prathamo 'dhy\={a}ya\d{h}}
```

But I'm not sure how to go about it.

I'd prefer to modify an existing command, like `\chapter`, as I've been burned in the past when I've tried to define my own sectioning commands from scratch. Moreover, all chapters in this document will be in this style and only this style, and as they are chapters, it would make sense for the command used to be called `\chapter`

Answer (score 1):

Well my approach was to get under the bonnet and go to work on `report`'s `\@chapter` and `\@makechapterhead`

```
\documentclass[12pt,final]{report}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage[margin=1.8cm]{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\SA}[Script=Devanagari]{Sanskrit 2003}

\makeatletter
\def\@chapter[#1]#2#3{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                         \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                         \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
                                   {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
                    \else
                      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                    \fi
                    \chaptermark{#1}%
                    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \if@twocolumn
                      \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}{#3}]%
                    \else
                      \@makechapterhead{#2}{#3}%
                      \@afterheading
                    \fi}
\def\@makechapterhead#1#2{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \Huge #1
    \par\nobreak
    \Huge #2\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{{\SA अथ प्रथमोऽध्यायः}}{\tlit{Atha prathamo 'dhy\={a}ya\d{h}}}

{\SA धृतराष्ट्र उवाच । \\
धर्मक्षेत्रे कुरुक्षेत्रे समवेता युयुत्सवः । \\
मामकाः पाण्डवाश्चैव किमकुर्वत सञ्जय ॥ १-१ ॥}

\end{document}
```

It certainly looks just right, but I don't know if I have sinned anywhere!